# How to remove extra space on right side of Text when using TextOverflow.ellipsis

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here is a code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home()));
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          color: Colors.green[200],
          child: Text(
            'https://someurl.com/4792479008289298462374623746723457',
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the result is not exactly what I expected:
[image]

but I need something like this:
[image]

`softWrap` doesn't help in this case

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following the Github issue: [Text overflow with ellipsis is weird and ugly by design](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18761)

Here is a quick fix for it:

> 1. The `TextOverflow.ellipsis` uses a regex pattern `\u2026`, you can apply a regex pattern[`\u{200B}`] on the `Text data`

Code :

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          color: Colors.green[200],
          child: Text(
            'https://someurl.com/479247900828929846'.replaceAll("", "\u{200B}"),
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

> 2. Use the flutter package which gives you the ability to do this [Assorted Layout Widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/assorted_layout_widgets)

Comment: Nice solution!!

Comment: Good answer! But in the revisions there is an edit marked with `Added more description`, what is the added description? I don't get why it's edited just to make OUTPUT bold and it's marked with `Added more description`.. @jitsm555

Comment: nice, thank very halpfully